# Find out if point is part of curve (spline, splipy)

Tags: geometry, point, curve, spline

I have some coordinates of a 3D point curve through which I lay a spline like so:

```
from splipy import curve_factory
pts = [...] #3D coordinate points
curve = curve_factory.curve(pts)
```

I know that I can get a point in 3D along the curve by evaluating it after a certain length:

```
point_on_curve = curve.evaluate(t)
print(point_on_curve) #outputs coordinates: (x y z)
```

Is it however somehow possible to do it the other way round? Is there a function/method that can tell me if a certain point is part of the curve? Or if its almost part of the curve? Something like:

```
curve.func(point) #output: True
```

or

```
curve.func(point) #output: distance to curve 0.0001 --> also part of curve
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've found this [script](https://gist.github.com/ventusff/91628e5c98800b52f81b0cde55a71046) by [ventusff](https://gist.github.com/ventusff) that performs an optimization to find the value of the parameter that you call `t` (in the script is `u`) which gives the point on the spline closest to the external point.

I report below the code with some changes to make it clearer for you. I've defined a tolerance equal to 0.001.
The selection of the optimization solver and of its parameter values requires a little bit of study. I do not have enough time now for doing that, but you can try to experiment a little bit.

In this case SciPy is used for spline generation and evaluation, but you can easily replace it with splipy. The optimization is the interesting part performed using SciPy.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
from scipy.optimize import fmin_bfgs

points_count = 40
phi = np.linspace(0, 2. * np.pi, points_count)
k = np.linspace(0, 2, points_count)
r = 0.5 + np.cos(phi)
x, y, z = r * np.cos(phi), r * np.sin(phi), k

tck, u = splprep([x, y, z], s=1)
points = splev(u, tck)

idx = np.random.randint(low=0, high=40)
noise = np.random.normal(scale=0.01)
external_point = np.array([points[0][idx], points[1][idx], points[2][idx]]) + noise


def distance_to_point(u_):
    s = splev(u_, tck)
    return euclidean(external_point, [s[0][0], s[1][0], s[2][0]])


closest_u = fmin_bfgs(distance_to_point, x0=np.array([0.0]), gtol=1e-8)
closest_point = splev(closest_u, tck)

tol = 1e-3
if euclidean(external_point, [closest_point[0][0], closest_point[1][0], closest_point[2][0]]) < tol:
    print("The point is very close to the spline.")

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot(points[0], points[1], points[2], "r-", label="Spline")
ax.plot(external_point[0], external_point[1], external_point[2], "bo", label="External Point")
ax.plot(closest_point[0], closest_point[1], closest_point[2], "go", label="Closest Point")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The script draws the plot below:

[image]

and prints the following output:

```
Current function value: 0.000941
Iterations: 5
Function evaluations: 75
Gradient evaluations: 32
The point is very close to the spline.
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That looks pretty good